# How to set up Azure DevOps notifications to receive after pipeline run fails?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have two pipelines defined in AzureDevOps, the second (deploy) is triggered when the first (build) succeeds.
I have also a branch policy to run build pipeline after each merge to master.

By default, Azure DevOps is set up in a way that I receive an email notification when the build pipeline completes, but I receive no notification after completion of the deployment. How can I receive notifications also for the deploy pipeline?

If triggered manually, the notifications for deployment are being sent, but not when triggered by the build pipeline.

Note that these are both pipelines (defined in YAML), not a pipeline and a release.

Comment: All notification related settings can be found at https://dev.azure.com/my_organization/my_project/_settings/notifications . Please follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/manage-team-group-global-organization-notifications?view=azure-devops) to add one more subscription for `Release` as Category and `A deployment is completed`. Click `Next` and add `Filter criteria` for `Field` as **Deployment status** with value `Succeeded`.

Comment: As I said in the original post, this is not a release object but a yaml pipeline. Nevertheless I was able to set up proper notification following your instruction but choosing Build instead of Release.

Comment: To avoid misunderstanding: the methods I've described **can be used in a YAML pipeline**.

Answer (score 2):

I have reproduced the issue.

**If configuring the pipeline triggers in yaml, the notification won't be sent. However, when I configure the triggers in Classic UI, the notification will be sent normally.**

Here are the steps about setting build completion triggers using classic UI:

In the edit page of the deploy pipeline, click "More actions" button in upper right corner and select "Triggers":

[image]

Then, add a build completion and specify your build pipeline.

Comment: ideally the triggers would be defined in yaml, but this may be a workaround to go with

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution, you can try [CatLight](https://catlight.io) tool.

It will show desktop [notifications for Azure DevOps builds, releases, PRs and work items](https://catlight.io/a/azure-devops-build-release-notifications). So, you will get a desktop alert whenever build or release pipeline fails.

[image: Build failure notification]

[image]

The tool is free for small teams and open-source projects.